# Nvidia Driver Deactivates Fans

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, cuda

To begin I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a headless server, and my Nvidia driver version is 450.51.05. I have one Nvidia 2080 Ti installed in the server. For whatever reason, the driver maintains the fans at 0% at all times by default, unless manually changed. I made a short script to set the fans to 100% at startup, so I'm not asking for a fix. I also have observed this with multiple other GPUs of the same model that were previously installed in this machine, and also on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS when using the same driver version. The common denominator seems to be the driver, which I think was installed with the `cuda-toolkit`. Before installing the `cuda-toolkit` on the machine, the fans have a reasonable default behaviour. My question is if this intended behaviour for the driver to deactivate the fans, and if not, has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: I use greenwithenvy to set/make fan profiles for my graphics card you can get it here (https://gitlab.com/leinardi/gwe) and i use startup applications to have it launch at login